# How can I group by date the output in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I need to show something like this in my template:

**11 June**

- Data 1
- Data 2

**10 June**

- Data 3
- Data 4

My view:

```
def Inicio(request):
    g = Gastos.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'principal/gastos.html', {'g': g})
```

My model:

```
class Gastos(models.Model):
    ...
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    ...
```

I need to group by day of the field "fecha" from Model, and I have no idea how to do this.

**EDIT**
I used collections.defaultdict:

My view:

```
def Inicio(request):
    g = Gastos.objects.all()
    lista = defaultdict(list)
    for gasto in g:
        lista['%s %s' %(gasto.fecha.day, gasto.fecha.strftime("%B"))].append(gasto)
    return render(request, 'principal/gastos.html', {'lista': lista})
```

If I print "lista" in python shell:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {"12 June": [<Gastos: Gasolina>, <Gastos: mandado>], "13 June": [<Gastos: Ropa>]})
```

I got that I want, but the problem is in templates, i can't iterate over each objects.

My template:

```
{% for dia in lista %}
    <h3>{{dia}}</h3>
    {% for g in dia.items %}
        <li>{{g.producto}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Result in html(without data):

**12 June**

**13 June**

Comment: pls take a look at `collections.defaultdict`, through which you can group data according to date.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I used collections.defaultdict as you said, can you check the edited question please?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Only prints the "12 June" but I can't iterate over objects inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lista` is a dictionary so we are free to apply `items` function on a dictionary to get key, value pair. So the code should be like,

```
{% for key, value in lista.items %}
    <h3>{{key}}</h3>
    {% for g in value %}
        <li>{{g.producto}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `for dia in lista` iterates only through the dict keys.

Comment: I had to convert the defaultdict() in a normal dictionary with dict() function, and then I sent it to the template, and in template I used "for key, value in lista.iteritems" because I'm using Python 2.7, thank you so much ;)

Comment: defaultdict obj is already a dict obj, you just need to replace `items` with `iteritems`

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work, I don't know why, I think defaultdict has more information like "type" which templates cannot interpret, but you help me to solve my problem, so answer accepted ;)